# Emacs right align on ')'

Tags: c++, emacs, alignment

I would like to perform an alignment on emacs that produce the following effect:

```
 m_str     ( "some value"     ),      
 m_frameCount  (0),                     
 m_filteredVolume(1.34 ),             
 m_filteredRawVolume (  -32.f, 0),     
 m_integratedValues( params->intVals),
 m_integratedScaledValues  (0),
```

to

```
m_str(                 "some value" ), 
m_frameCount(                     0 ), 
m_filteredVolume(              1.34 ), 
m_filteredRawVolume(       -32.f, 0 ), 
m_integratedValues( params->intVals ), 
m_integratedScaledValues(         0 ),
```

I've been playing around with align-regexp, trying to change the matching pattern and left/right alignment without any success. Note: I definitely want the first '(' to be concatenated to the first string.

Comment: Is this for XEmacs or Emacs or both?

Comment: My question is for emacs, but I guess the answer will be also good for xemacs, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following function, given a region, first it gets rid of excess white space, then it does right alignment.

```
(defun cpp-right-align-format ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((begin (region-beginning))
          (end (region-end)))
      (replace-regexp "\\s-*(\\s-*" "( " nil begin end)
      (replace-regexp "\\s-*)" " )" nil begin end)
      (align-regexp begin end "\\([^(]*\\))," -1)))
```